# Layout glitch: Nesting RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

**Problem:** I want to clarify a very basic layout issue. I have been at it for 2 days to no avail. I simply want to successfully nest a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout and control its positioning. For this purpose, I have created 2 layouts: 1 layout to be displayed on the left and one on the right.

I am getting the following output:
You can see the second view should be on displayed on the right but its not. I have tried layout_gravity but its not working.

[image]

Following are the layouts:
**For left:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_view_border">

    <!--The message text-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <!--the timestamp-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**For right:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_view_border"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <!--The message text-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <!--the timestamp-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Activity that's working the scenario:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        //Get handle to the root view's child. i.e, FrameLayout
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
                .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.container_linear_layout);

        View message_receiver = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_message_receiver, viewGroup, false);
        TextView received_content = (TextView)message_receiver.findViewById(R.id.message_content);
        received_content.setText("okay");
        linearLayout.addView(message_receiver);

        View message_sender = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_message_sender, viewGroup, false);
        TextView sent_content = (TextView)message_sender.findViewById(R.id.message_content);
        sent_content.setText("okay");
        linearLayout.addView(message_sender);
    }
}
```

Project for your reference: https://github.com/mankum93/TestApp1

**Note:** I know that I have asked a similar question with no answer to it. I am asking this again because people questioned in the question about the RecyclerView I was using to populate a dynamic list of views. That may have been the reason that no one could identify the root cause of the problem. But since, the problem is a fundamental one which exists even without a RecyclerView, I think, it deserves another chance.

I have searched several forums, docs, and SO posts but can't resolve this problem.

**EDIT 1:** I can see the source of confusion here: 
Here it the main activity layout file:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/container_linear_layout">

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Floating view to send messages layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/typed_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: No need to use profanity in your screenshots. It is pretty unprofessional.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Sorry about that. Edited.

Comment: What orientation does your LinearLayout have and is there a reason you are adding the layouts in Java instead of xml?

Comment: Did you set android:orientation="horizontal" for your LinearLayout?

Comment: @codeMagic : LinearLayout has vertical orientation. There is no paricular reason to add them in Java. I just want to separate out the issue of layout and have temporarily set them in Java. When it gets resolved, I will incorporate the solution the listview that is based on above layout. So, basically, it is just for demonstration of problem.

Comment: Then that's your issue. It's going to put them in order vertically. Remove that as LinearLayout is horizontal by default. Also, it's much easier to do in xml so there's not a good reason to do it in Java to try and figure out the problem. Much easier to figure out directly in xml. Also, I have a sneaky feeling that you may want a RelativeLayout as the root but that's up to your design

Comment: @DmitriTimofti : See the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are inflating your Views:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_message_sender, viewGroup, false);
```

The second parameter to `inflate()` is a root ViewGroup, which is the parent of the View you are inflating. You are passing the third parameter (`attachToRoot`) as false, but the `LayoutInflater` will still use that root ViewGroup to generate a set of `LayoutParams`.

In your case, you are passing the root `FrameLayout` of your activity as the root to the inflater, when in reality you are going to be attaching your views to the `LinearLayout`.

Changing those inflation lines like so will fix your problem:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_message_sender, linearLayout, false);
```

Comment: This still won't fix the problem since he's using a vertical LinearLayout. Especially since  he says he plans on adding it back into the xml after he figures out the issue.

Comment: @codeMagic I think you are misunderstanding the issue (or maybe I am). OP doesn't want the two things in the same line as each other. OP wants the two bubbles to be on separate lines, but with one left-aligned and on right-aligned. Based on the context of this being a chat application, I'm guessing he is going for the now-typical messenger style layout.

Comment: Ah, you might be right. I just read the left and right part since that's all we were given.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That solved it. I always ignored the root viewgroup passed on to the inflater because I knew about the fact that if you pass "false", it won't be a problem but I never knew about the generation of layoutparams based on it. Thank You.